# Blank or empty field in a list item using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, list-item, item, isblank

What is considered an empty SharePoint list item when doing if else condition via JavaScript?  "", null, or something else?

Comment: What field type are you checking?

Comment: @michael-colbs, Hello, string type

Comment: `if (listitem["field"])` only this should work

Answer (score 0):

I just did an alert to show what the empty list item was showing.  It showed null.  SO I i changed it to

```
if (whatever("whatever")==="" || whatever("whatever")=null)...
```

it now shows what I want to show.